# How to pass sparse matrix as reference between functions in Eigen

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix, eigen

Wondering how I can pass sparse matrices between functions in Eigen. I have been using dense matrices as shown below.  Size of K can be anywhere between 2000 and 10000.  However the matrix K has less than 1% non zero elements. Therefore sparse matrix would be much more efficient in this case. I found one example that talks about creating template based function, but I am struggling to understand how to write such a function in this case. Also is there a way to add vector M without converting it to a diagonal. M is a vector of unit value.

```
#include "Eigen/Core"
#include "Eigen/LU"
#include "Eigen/Sparse"


using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;
void FuncA (Eigen::MatrixXd& K, Eigen::VectorXd& M, int rows, 
            double D, double perM,Eigen::MatrixXd& retMat) 
{

  int i,j, k;

  
  Eigen::MatrixXd mMat(rows,rows);


  mMat.setZero();
  mMat = M.asDiagonal();

  retMat.setZero();
  retMat = K + (K*D) + mMat/perM;      
  mMat.resize(0,0);
}
```

Comment: Not sure what your actual problem is. You can pass `Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>` by reference.

Comment: Thank you. That seems to work.